# Microphone Pi 3 USB audio

Tags: pi-3, usb, audio

how can I use a USB audio key on my raspberry pi 3? I would like to plug a microphone into the Pi and record my voice.

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to do this is to connect a USB microphone to your Pi, open a terminal window and run the following command:

```
arecord /home/pi/Desktop/a.wav -D sysdefault:CARD=1
```

The Pi will then start recording sound from the microphone. When you have finished recording leave a gap of 6 seconds then press CTRL+X on your keyboard to close the terminal window. The file will save automatically.

The `/home/pi/Desktop` part of the command determines the save location of the file and the `a.wav` part is the name of the file

To playback the file run:

```
omxplayer -p -o hdmi /home/pi/Desktop/a.wav
```